# Regex em Javascript: agrupando

Tags: javascript, regex

Como entrada por parte do usuário estou esperando pares de números separados por vírgulas:

```
// se for um par só
1-2

// se for mais de um par
1-2,3-4,5-6
```

Espero da saída algo assim:

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
]
```

Eu estou em dúvida em como obter essa saída em Javascript.

Código até aqui no JSFiddle (tá dando loop infinito): http://jsfiddle.net/cbLs8/7/

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada" value="1-2,3-4,5-6"></input>
<button id="botao">Testar</button>
```

---

```
$("#botao").click(function () {
    var regex = new RegExp(/(\d+)-(\d+)/);
    var match;
    var string = $("#entrada").val();
    if (match = regex.exec(string)) {
        while (match !== null) {
            console.log(match);
            match = regex.exec(string)
        }
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }
});
```

Comment: Que tal `/((\d+)-(\d+))+/`?

Comment: É isto que quer?: http://jsfiddle.net/cbLs8/8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma simples, o delimitador para expressões regulares é a barra `/`. Se você passar uma string para o construtor, não deve passar as barras dentro da string, senão serão interpretadas como literais. Então use assim:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(\d+)-(\d+)/);
```

Ou assim:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
```

Note o uso de duplo *escapes* para os dígitos. Um para o literal da string e outro para a regex propriamente dito.

Mas nem faz sentido declarar o tipo explicitamente, pode usar apenas assim:

```
var regex = /(\d+)-(\d+)/;
```

Agora, se você precisa usar o método `exec` múltiplas vezes na mesma string, deve habilitar a opção `g`:

```
var regex = /(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
```

Ou:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "g");
```

Isso é tudo, sua lógica funciona. Mas usar expressões regulares é realmente necessário? Para processamentos simples como o seu, usar uma regex é excessivo. Além de ser mais lento, deixa o código pouco legível. Você pode fazer o mesmo muito mais diretamente.

No caso, você tem uma sequencia de partes que usa a vírgula como separador

```
"1-2,3-4,5-6".split(",");
    // => ["1-2", "3-4", "5-6"]
```

Cada uma delas é um par separado por um hífen:

```
"1-2,3-4,5-6".split(",").map(function(s) {return s.split("-")});
    // => [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]]
```

Você pode ainda transformar cada string em um número se quiser usando mais um nível de `map`.

Em resumo: Use regex para procurar por um padrão dentro de um texto maior ou para validar por alto uma entrada. Não use regex para fazer parse de strings, em particular nesses casos simples.

Comment: Dá pra dar um destaque na última parte? "Pra que regex" foi a primeira coisa que pensei quando li a pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto expliquei um pouco mais.

Comment: Valeu Guilherme!

Comment: Perfeito! Agradeço a sugestão Guilherme e @bfavaretto, realmente fica bem mais simples assim, com `split` e `map`. =)

Comment: A quem interessar ver no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PU5CZ/2/

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema está no `while` e na expressão regular que está utilizando. Para executá-la múltiplas vezes, você tem que utilizar a opção `g`. Veja mais detalhes [no site da mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Utilize a expressão regular: `/[(\d-\d)]+/gi`

**Exemplo**

Html:

```
<ul id="out"></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $out = $("#out");
var re = /[(\d-\d)]+/gi
var str = "1-2,3-4,5-6";

do{ 
    var x = re.exec(str);
    if (x == null)
        break; 

    $out.append("<li>" + x + "</li>");
}while(x != null);
```

O exemplo está aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/andrenmaia/sNHqD/4/

Comment: Sua resposta foi útil, não sabia que tinha que ter o `g`. Obrigado!